# how disabled auto complete on sublime text on specific key?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Each time when I press a key, autocomplete menu apear like this :
[image: autocomplete]

That right, but how can I disabled this behaviour on specific key ?

In practice, when I press `{` for my css in my exemple, after I press `ENTER` immediatly for make new line (to close it with `}`), but instead go at line, it's validate the autocomplete (normal behaviour).

How disabled autocomplete on specials key like `{ [` ?

Comment: Can you please give a concrete example, preferably with images? It's hard to tell exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: I edit with a screen. Immediatly after I press a key, there is autocomplete menu, but for { and [ it's boring, I have to press escape before press enter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override key :

```
{ "keys": ["altgr+'"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "{"}},
```

TIPS: use `sublime.log_input(True)` in console to find real key pressed (in this case `'` instead of `{`)